# Metaphor and Symbolism in The Story of "The God of Peace"

Tags: monster

My question is about the story of "The God of peace" by Kalus Poppe in the anime "Monster". It seems that this story is full of metaphor and symbolism. I never quite understood what is metaphor and symbolism behind of this story. 
In regards to the series and the story itself.

One opinion can be that Johan can change everything to evil even though he is the God of peace and the conclusion is that there is no solution for conquering him.

Another opinion is that everybody has a bad characteristic how much he or she is good.

Comment: In regards to the series or the story itself?

Comment: I am interested in both of them.

Comment: Please specify that in your question body and title.